# WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.accumulo.start.classloader.AccumuloClassLoader)

Tags: log4j, accumulo

Does anyone know how to get rid of the following warnings when starting accumulo:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.accumulo.start.classloader.AccumuloClassLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

I am running accumulo 1.4.0 hadoop 0.20.2 and zookeeper 3.3.3.  I understand this warning happens because the class can not find the log4j.properties file and yes I have read http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html.  My log4j.properties file has the following lines copied from an accumulo 1.4.3 log4j file (I dont have the option to upgrade my system to 1.4.3):

```
# default logging properties:
#  by default, log everything at INFO or higher to the console
log4j.rootLogger=INFO,A1


# hide Jetty junk
log4j.logger.org.mortbay.log=WARN,A1

# hide "Got brand-new compresssor" messages
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.io.compress=WARN,A1

# hide junk from TestRandomDeletes
log4j.logger.org.apache.accumulo.server.test.TestRandomDeletes=WARN,A1

# hide almost everything from zookeeper
log4j.logger.org.apache.zookeeper=ERROR,A1

# hide AUDIT messages in the shell, alternatively you could send them to a different logger
log4j.logger.org.apache.accumulo.core.util.shell.Shell.audit=WARN,A1

# Send most things to the console
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} [%-8c{2}] %-5p: %m%n
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```

I have put this log4j file everyone.  In the accumulo/bin folder, in the accumulo/conf folder, in the accumulo/lib folder but can not get rid of this warning (I know it has to go on the accumulo class path but dont know where that is).  I also can't pass a log4j.configuration option to the java compiler because the accmulo executable comes pre-compiled (I just run it).

Thanks in advance for the help.

EDIT:  Below is the result of an "accumulo classpath" command on my system:

```
[admin-cloud@NODE1 bin]$ echo $ACCUMULO_HOME
/accumulo/accumulo-1.4.0
[admin-cloud@NODE1 bin]$ accumulo classpath
Accumulo List of classpath items are:
file:/accumulo/accumulo-1.4.0/lib/commons-collections-3.2.jar
file:/accumulo/accumulo-1.4.0/lib/commons-configuration-1.5.jar
file:/accumulo/accumulo-1.4.0/lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar
file:/accumulo/accumulo-1.4.0/lib/libthrift-0.6.1.jar
file:/accumulo/accumulo-1.4.0/lib/commons-jci-core-1.0.jar
file:/accumulo/accumulo-1.4.0/lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar
file:/accumulo/accumulo-1.4.0/lib/commons-logging-api-1.0.4.jar
file:/accumulo/accumulo-1.4.0/lib/accumulo-server-1.4.0.jar
file:/accumulo/accumulo-1.4.0/lib/accumulo-start-1.4.0.jar
file:/accumulo/accumulo-1.4.0/lib/commons-jci-fam-1.0.jar
file:/accumulo/accumulo-1.4.0/lib/jline-0.9.94.jar
file:/accumulo/accumulo-1.4.0/lib/examples-simple-1.4.0.jar
file:/accumulo/accumulo-1.4.0/lib/cloudtrace-1.4.0.jar
file:/accumulo/accumulo-1.4.0/lib/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
file:/accumulo/accumulo-1.4.0/lib/accumulo-core-1.4.0.jar
file:/accumulo/accumulo-1.4.0/lib/commons-io-1.4.jar
file:/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.3.6/zookeeper-3.3.6.jar
file:/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/conf/
file:/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/hadoop-0.20.2-examples.jar
file:/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/hadoop-0.20.2-test.jar
file:/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/hadoop-0.20.2-tools.jar
file:/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/hadoop-0.20.2-ant.jar
file:/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/hadoop-0.20.2-core.jar
file:/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar
file:/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.12.jar
file:/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.4.3.jar
file:/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/lib/commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar
file:/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/lib/mockito-all-1.8.0.jar
file:/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/lib/jetty-6.1.14.jar
file:/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/lib/oro-2.0.8.jar
file:/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/lib/servlet-api-2.5-6.1.14.jar
file:/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/lib/junit-3.8.1.jar
file:/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/lib/commons-logging-api-1.0.4.jar
file:/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/lib/commons-codec-1.3.jar
file:/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/lib/core-3.1.1.jar
file:/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/lib/jets3t-0.6.1.jar
file:/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/lib/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar
file:/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/lib/slf4j-api-1.4.3.jar
file:/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.12.jar
file:/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/lib/jetty-util-6.1.14.jar
file:/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/lib/commons-net-1.4.1.jar
file:/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/lib/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
file:/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar
file:/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar
file:/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/lib/kfs-0.2.2.jar
file:/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar
```

Comment: What's the output of `accumulo classpath` and what did you set $ACCUMULO_HOME to? Also, what are the contents of your $ACCUMULO_HOME/conf/accumulo-env.sh? You should see the value of $ACCUMULO_HOME/conf in the output for that command. Finally, the `accumulo` executable is a shell script, not a compiled binary.

Comment: Whats the output of accumulo classpath:  all the jars in /hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/lib and /accumulo/accumulo-1.4.0/lib as well as /zookeeper/zookeeper-3.3.6/zookeeper-3.3.6.jar and /hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/conf

Comment: $ACCUMULO_HOME is /accumulo/accumulo-1.4.0.  The accumulo.env.sh is the same as the 2GB_standalone example that comes with the accumulo install.

Comment: Lastly, I think "accumulo" is a compiled binary, not a shell script (try vi accumulo and you get garbage, if it were a shell script you could read it).  You may be referring to "start-all.sh", which (eventually) calls accumulo and is indeed a shell script.

Comment: I find it odd the /accumulo/accumulo-1.4.0/conf is not on the classpath but the hadoop conf is?  That may very well be my problem.

Comment: No, the 'accumulo' executable in Apache Accumulo 1.4.0 is not binary; it is a shell script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line 84 of bin/accumulo in Apache Accumulo 1.4.0 sets the variable XML_FILES to $ACCUMULO_HOME/conf and then adds XML_FILES to the CLASSPATH variable which is later passed to the java command.

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/accumulo/tags/1.4.0/bin/accumulo

It sounds you have a misconfiguration of ACCUMULO_HOME either through your shell environment or in $ACCUMULO_HOME/conf/accumulo-env.sh.

Comment: see my edit to the question.  I believe you that this is what happens in the accumulo shells script (I was incorrect about that), but this is not what is being returned by the accumulo classpath command.  I solved this problems by placing the log4j files in the hadoop/conf folder, which is obviously not the right was to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

I was troubleshooting an installation someone else set up that was having the same problem.  My solution to this problem was simply that there actually was no log4j.properties in the conf directory!  So I just copied up one of the log4j.properties from the conf/examples directory, restarted and everything worked like it should!

Comment: when you run "accumulo classpath" is accumulo/conf listed?

Comment: no it's not. But earlier I did check to make sure that directory is added to the CLASSPATH variable in the script (i echo-ed it).  why do you ask (curious cause mine is working now i added the log4j.properties)?

Comment: Mine has been working for some time, I was just trying to reconcile the inconsistencies in how accumulo/conf gets into the classpath.  See the comments under my main question.  It must be a versioning thing with accumulo...